# Does it make sens to put a (meta charset="") element in a (title) element?

Tags: html, character-encoding, head

I'm going through the HTML beginner guide in the webplatform.org website and at (the HTML <head>) page in the (Setting your document's character encoding) section i'm not sure I understand that sentence:

> It is, however, important to understand that just putting (meta charset="utf-8") in your title element doesn't magically convert your page to a UTF-8 encoding.

Do they mean, in your head element?

[link to the page section](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/the_html_head#Setting_your_document.27s_character_encoding)

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure they mean in the `<head>` element.  The `<title>` element should contain only text.

Comment: Aside from a typo, it doesn't make any sense to me. So, yes, they must mean head instead of title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they mean the `head` element. That’s the only context where a `meta` tag for character encoding may validly appear. And a `title` element can contain only text, no tags.